# Hadoop 2.7.0 - MapReduce Jobs not Running - Failing with AM Container Error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using **Hadoop 2.7.0 in pseudo node mode, on a Fedora 22 Virtual Machine**. A few days back the MapReduce jobs ran fine, but after installed Oozie and made modifications to the **yarn-site.xml** . I am getting the below error on running the Pi example job and come what may I am not able to debug the error,

**EDITED** - I am running the job using command line and **NOT** using the oozie workflow engine .. command - hadoop jar  10 100

```
Starting Job
15/12/17 15:22:05 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /192.168.122.1:8032
15/12/17 15:22:06 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 10
15/12/17 15:22:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:10
15/12/17 15:22:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1450326099697_0001
15/12/17 15:22:07 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1450326099697_0001
15/12/17 15:22:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoop:8088/proxy/application_1450326099697_0001/
15/12/17 15:22:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1450326099697_0001
15/12/17 15:22:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1450326099697_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/12/17 15:22:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:22:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 10% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:22:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:22:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 30% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:22:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 40% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:22:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:22:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 60% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:22:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 70% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:23:01 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 80% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:23:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 90% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:23:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:23:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/12/17 15:23:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: vlan722-rsvd-router.ddr.priv/192.168.122.1:34460. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3,     
                                   sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/12/17 15:23:24 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: vlan722-rsvd-router.ddr.priv/192.168.122.1:34460. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, 
                                   sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/12/17 15:23:25 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: vlan722-rsvd-router.ddr.priv/192.168.122.1:34460. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, 
                                    sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/12/17 15:23:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/12/17 15:23:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1450326099697_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1450326099697_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for 
                                    appattempt_1450326099697_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://hadoop:8088/cluster/app/application_1450326099697_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1450326099697_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
15/12/17 15:23:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
Job Finished in 82.924 seconds
Estimated value of Pi is 3.14800000000000000000
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>
         /home/osboxes/hadoop/etc/hadoop, 
         /home/osboxes/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*, 
         /home/osboxes/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*, 
         /home/osboxes/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*, 
         /home/osboxes/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*, 
         /home/osboxes/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*, 
         /home/osboxes/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*,
         /home/osboxes/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,     
         /home/osboxes/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
    </value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>5120</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>1024</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>http://192.168.122.1:8032</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>http://192.168.122.1:8030</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>http://192.168.122.1:8031</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
    <value>http://192.168.122.1:8041</value>
</property>
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT** - yarn-site.xml **before**

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

Comment: What modifications did you do to yarn-site.xml? Can you explain?

Comment: @ManjunathBallur - Added Edit to show how yarn-site.xml looked before making necessary changes for OOZIE

Comment: Since you are using Oozie, I am assuming your Oozie workflow has chain of jobs. It seems, first job is successful. But, while launching the second job, container launching fails. It would help, me to know, about your Oozie workflow and what settings are you doing in your Oozie properties etc.

Comment: @ManjunathBallur - I am not using oozie to run the jobs and am not using a workflow to run this. I am just running the job directly using the command-line.

Comment: I see this in the output: "Estimated value of Pi is 3.14800000000000000000".  It seems to me that job is correctly outputting the value of Pi.

Comment: vishant, is this pseudo node cluster or multinode cluster. ? in the AM the container is killed and it will retry it for another time and get killed !! may be tit was due to  Memory problem. MAX allocation memory is 5 GB and ensure the RAM size too.

Comment: @karthik- I am running Hadoop in pseudo mode with 8GB allocated to the cluster. Initially I came across the memory error and debugged it with 5GB RAM allocation to the AM container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue by making the following change to **mapred-site.xml** ,

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>http://localhost:19888</value>
</property>
```

After that the jobs ran perfectly fine.